# Javascript assertion libraries - chai vs check-types

Tags: javascript, tdd, chai

I see two popular libraries in NPM - chai and check-types. I am trying to understand their intended purpose.

I know that chai is used for unit testing TDD/BDD style and has a rich assertion library.

check-types (https://github.com/philbooth/check-types.js) on the other hand is simply an assertion library to check for arguments to be of the correct types. Does not look like this is meant to be used for unit testing. I am assuming this is to be used inside my Javascript functions to ensure that argument types passed into the function are of the expected type.

So the question is check-types library redundant if chai already supports a rich assertion library? Or are they meant for different uses? Can I use chai in my code also (outside of my tests) to check for variables to be of the right type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already assumed correctly, there are two different use cases here:

**chai** is an Assertion-Library intended just for tests - and therefore it is not optimized in any way to run within a normal app. There is no minifed version of it and requiring it brings you a lot of library code for different possibilities of testing styles (`should`, `expect` and `assert`). And the most important: If a condition for an assertion is **not** met, chai will immidiately throw a special `AssertionError` that is intended to be processed by popular test-harnesses like *Karma* or *Mocha*.

**check-types** on the other hand is just intended to make type- and value-checking easier and more readable **within an app**. In most cases, it let's you decide what to do when an assertion is not met (doesn't throw).

## CONCLUSION:

While of course you could use chai outside of your tests, I definitly wouldn't recommend it as it would just increase the size of your build with lots of unused methods and you would need a `try{} catch(){}` block around every assertion.

And while you could use **check-types** for your tests, you would need to throw the `AssertionErrors` for every test yourself (which is tiresome).

So: No, none of both libraries is redundant. You can think of chai as a kind of superset of libraries like **check-types** (**chai** itself uses it's own type-detection library called [type-detect](https://github.com/chaijs/type-detect) (Of which I am one of the maintainers ;) )) that utilizes them for usage within test-harnesses.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The difference is clear now.

Comment: Could you be so kind and mark it as the answer? Thanks! :)